# FB.Canvas.getPageInfo no return in callback function

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
 function getpageinfo()
{
alert('start');
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
  alert('got');
        alert('Width: ' + info.clientWidth + ' Height: ' + info.clientHeight);
    }
alert('end');
}
```

---

i have loaded  facebook javascript jdk, 
also have    ,and  FB.init() before call this function ,

but when call the function there only have two alert  "start" and "end" , 
i never  got   the alert "got" , seems the  FB.Canvas.getPageInfo's  callback function never worked .

does the FB.Canvas.getPageInfo really can work ?
or can someone give me a url which  used this method and workd ? 
very thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Your `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(` doesn't have a closing bracket.